# Trying to repeat string in MySQL syntax, getting syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small issue with my syntax, I am trying to accomplish a project and I have a slight issue.

```
<?php
include('includes/db_credentials.php');

// connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// connection chck
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Check strings for strings
$primary_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['primary_name']);
$primary_mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['primary_mobile']);
$primary_country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['primary_country']);
$primary_state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['primary_state']);



$rand = rand(1,999999999);
$times = 2;
$rpt =  str_repeat("('$primary_name', '$primary_mobile', '$primary_country', '$primary_state', '$rand;'), ", $times);




$sql = "INSERT INTO cards (primary_name, primary_mobile, primary_country, primary_state, card_code)
VALUES $rpt";




if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    $id = mysqli_insert_id();
    echo $id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}






$conn->close();
?>
```

> Error: INSERT INTO cards (primary_name, primary_mobile, primary_country, primary_state, card_code) VALUES ('John Doe', '000 000 0000', 'Afghanistan', 'Badghis', '23605621;'), ('John Doe', '000 000 0000', 'Afghanistan', 'Badghis', '23605621;'),
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

I am getting the following MySQL return message, I have been reading here on stackoverflow on the ways to insert multiple rows at once and this is the closest I can get to it, would anyone be able to give me a slight pointer on where I'm doing wrong and or point me in a better direction.
Thanks.

Comment: See the trailing comma at the end of the query? Get rid of it.

Comment: There's a comma at the end of your statement. rtrim($sql, ',') it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma after your values. I'd suggest doing an [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) instead, and then [imploding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it.

```
 $rpt =  array_fill(0,$times,"('$primary_name', '$primary_mobile', '$primary_country', '$primary_state', '$rand') ");
 $values = implode(',',$rpt);
```

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply, this seemed to work perfectly. I upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably hitting the issue whereby the last of your repeated inserts has a comma at the end of it too when the comma isn't needed. Also there's a semi-colon after $rand (is that suppose to be there?)

**Quick fix**
I've taken the space off the end of your string then I just trim the very last comma in that final string. This keeps your code pretty much the same.

```
$rpt = str_repeat("('$primary_name', '$primary_mobile', '$primary_country', '$primary_state', '$rand;'),",$times);
$rpt = rtrim($rpt,",");
```

Comment: Silly me, I see the issue now with the last comma in the repeat, thanks for pointing that out.